# What is the meaning of hexadecimal number that see in strings of MAT report?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I used eclipse Memory Analysis Tool ( MAT ) to take a heap dump profile for a process on an android device. along with all objects I see a cryptic looking hexadecimal number

example:

android.graphics.Bitmap @ **0x428e5c90**

android.graphics.Bitmap @ **0x428f5888**

android.graphics.Bitmap @ **0x42717950**

android.graphics.Bitmap @ **0x426fed10**

Can anyone help me find out what these numbers are and also can i use them in tracking more specifically the items they are associated to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hash code. You can find that specific bitmap using Gimp

Steps to get bitmap

1] click on bitmap you will get its detail information in right-side pane.

2] click on mBuffer and right click on it, you will get options in that select copy --> save value to file save value with ".data" extension.

3] Now open that file on Gimp.

4] choose "Image type" as "RGB Alpha" set height and width as mentioned in mWidth and mHeight fields in MAT.

Answer (score 0):

That's HachCode of object, one of several things used for testing for equality, because Hashed values are more or less unique. For more information, refer to [source code of Object](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29)